# openrave_planning and dependencies on Debian Squeeze

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosmake, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Though I have ROS Diamondback installed and configured on Ubuntu 10.04, it's become necessary for me to also have an installation on Debian Squeeze.  I believe I have the installation working except for the openrave_planning stack.  When attempting to use rosmake to build I'm getting:

Failed to find rosdep collada-dom for package openrave_actionlib on OS:debian version:squeeze
Failed to find rosdep assimp2 for package openrave_actionlib on OS:debian version:squeeze

for each of the packages within the openrave_planning stack.  Is there a method of explicitly installing collada-dom and assimp2 such that openrave_planning will be able to use them?  Is there another place I can configure ROS to search for these dependencies such that they can be installed automatically through rosdep?

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue,

- Jeff

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29991/openrave_planning-and-dependencies-on-debian-squeeze/) by [js572](https://answers.ros.org/users/2011/js572/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In diamondback you can update the rosdep.yaml file in the openrave_planning stack to define a rule for debian squeeze.  You can just update your local copy of [this file](https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/openrave_planning/rosdep.yaml)

The rosdep dependencies are declared in the manifest.xml files. You can [see](https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/openrave_planning/openrave/manifest.xml) the openrave package declares a rosdep on assimp-dev. Any package which depends on the openrave package will require assimp-dev through the dependency.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0